# how to make withColumnRenamed query generic in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

Description
I have 2 lists

```
List1=['curentColumnName1','curentColumnName2','currentColumnName3']
List2=['newColumnName1','newColumnName2','newColumnName3']
```

Their is a dataframe df which contains all columns

I want to check like if column 'curentColumnName1 is present in dataframe,if yes then rename it to newColumnName1
Need to do this for all columns if those are present in dataframe

How to achieve this scenario using pyspark

Comment: Can you please confirm this: does the `currentColumnName` index from list1 matches the respective `newColumnName` from list2?

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the first list, check if it in the column list, and rename:

```py
for i in range(len(List1)):
  if List1[i] in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(List1[i], List2[i])
```

P.S. Instead of two lists, it's better to use dictionary - it's easier to maintain, and you can avoid errors when you add/remove elements only in one list

Comment: For ex:
I have a dictionary 

Dict={"currentColumnName1":"newColumnName1", "currentColumnName2":"newColumnName2"}

How to achieve the similar scenario using dictionary?

Comment: just iterate over the key/values: `for old_name, new_name in Dict.items()`, then use `old_name` instead of `List1[i]` and `new_name` instead of `List2[i]`

Comment: have you ever heard of `zip` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is anotherway of doing it in one-liner :

```py
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.withColumnRenamed(b[0], b[1]),
    zip(List1, List2),
    df,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in one line:

```
df.selectExpr(*[f"{old_col} AS {new_col}" for old_col, new_col in zip(List1, List2)]).show()
```

Comment: this is my choice of approach -- multiple `withColumnRenamed()` will create a new projection in the lineage for each of them, whereas the select just creates single for all of them. That said, this answer only selects the columns that are to be renamed, and not the rest of them. It'll be easy to achieve with df.columns and List1 intersection or other mechanisms.